# Why asp-route encodes get string parameter?

Tags: asp.net, query-string, anchor, urlencode

I tried two approaches to create a link:

1. `<a asp-page="/page" asp-route-param="[1]">`
2. `<a href="/page?param=[1]">`

And got two different addresses:

1. `../page?param=%5B1%5D`
2. `../page?param=[1]`

Why asp-route encodes get string parameter and why href doesn't?